# How to wipe-out square brackets from dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

Please help me
I have base: https://github.com/devsar/d3talk/blob/master/airports.csv

I create dictionary:

```
df2 = df[['ident','municipality']]
df2.set_index('ident').T.to_dict('list')
```

In the dictionary I have square brackets, how to throw it out?
[image]
How to wipe-out square brackets from dictionary?

Comment: die square brackets die! oh wait.. those are lists. Just access the 0th element of each value and make a new dict.

Comment: I don't understand you, I have thousands such positions. I cant help do it during the weeks.

Comment: can you provide a sample input to work with instead of an image?

Comment: I sent address to base that i used

Comment: what did you charge me with two points for?

Comment: [MCVE] makes it easier for answerers to verify your requirements, and provide clearer answers without guesswork. Avoid posting images, and try to provide MCVE whenever you need help with code. Take a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and a more specific [post for pandas mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I beleive you need create `Series` by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with select column after and convert to `dict`:

```
d = df.set_index('ident')['municipality'].to_dict()
```